# Mac OS X Lion and sshpass

Tags: macos, ssh, macports, osx-lion

I've upgraded from **Mac OS X Snow Leopard** to **Lion**. I used several scripts with `sshpass` but after I upgraded to Lion the following error appears:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 502
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
```

I can only connect with `sshpass` or type the password manually. No public/private key way. I've reinstalled MacPorts and sshpass.

How can I get ssh-askpass? How can I configure **/dev/tty** ?

Greets!

Comment: You should pose this question over at http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug in the sshpass that don't remove DISPLAY. Try to unset DISPLAY before run sshpass. EX:

```
unset DISPLAY; sshpass -p pass ssh host
```

Answer (score 0):

it stuck me for a long time, and finally found the hint [here](https://superuser.com/questions/393506/can-i-automatically-login-to-ssh-using-passwords-from-os-x-keychain):

in simplicity, if one wants to do something like following in **mac lion**:

> sshpass -p pass ssh user@host

he only needs to:

1. set up a script called **pass.sh** with following:

   > echo pass
2. set up the environment variable

   > export SSH_ASKPASS=~/bin/pass.sh
3. the ssh could now be done by this:

   > sshpass ssh user@host

If you want to get the password from the keychain, you better watch the second answer of this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/393506/can-i-automatically-login-to-ssh-using-passwords-from-os-x-keychain).